# android 2 list view in linear layout height wrap_content

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I have two list in a LinearLayout, and I want them to share the space between them according to their content,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/page_vierge"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:padding="5dp">



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_amis_fb"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:padding="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Amis "/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_amis"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

look at the picture
[image]

1: if content of if the list 1 is small and list 2 is longer

2: if content of if the list 2 is small and list 1 is longer

3: 2 lists are long

in my code when list 1 is long , list 2 is invisible !!

help.

Comment: never give list view height as WRAP_CONTENT. It should always be a fixed height or MATCH_PARENT for performance improvement

Comment: but you can take list view inside linear layout and you can easily set weight of linear layout.

Answer (score 1):

strong textyou should use `ExpandableListview` and **hide listview** **group header** and **always expand group** to get same effect that you want... see here

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: but I have 2 custom adapter for each list ?

Comment: make it as one and pass two Arrylist in it or make a model that contain two ArrayList and pass that model to adapter

Answer (score 0):

Have 3 conditions-
1: if the list 1 is small and list 2 is longer

2: if the list 2 is small and list 1 is longer

3: 2 lists are long

play with layout_weight property of LinearLayout children(the ListViews).

Answer (score 0):

you can set it by adding weight proprty, looke below code, i have added in that.you can change weight according to your requirment.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/page_vierge"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightsum="10"
android:padding="5dp">



<ListView
android:id="@+id/list_amis_fb"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:weight="4"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:divider="#00000000"
android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
android:padding="5dp" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:weight="2"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:text="Amis "/>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list_amis"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:weight="4"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:divider="#00000000"
android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

if you want 1st list long then you can set weight of 1st listview to "5",set textview weight to "1" and 2nd listview  weight to "4". change weight according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the adapters that fill the `ListViews` then you could simply compare the results of the `getCount()` function and set the `layout_height` attribute accordingly.

```
public void onCreate(...)
   ...
   ListView list1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_amis_fb);
   ListView list2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_amis);

   ListAdapter list1_adapter = ... //However you get your data
   ListAdapter list2_adapter = ...

   int count_difference = list1_adapter.getCount() - list2_adapter.getCount();
   if (count_difference < 0){
        list1.setLayoutParams(LayoutParams.match_parent, 100);
        list2.setLayoutParams(LayoutParams.match_parent, LayoutParams.fill_parent);
   }
   if (count_difference == 0)
   {
       ...
   }
```